# JS convert date string in ISO 8601 UTC to Date object

Tags: javascript, date

I have to parse a date string that looks like `20191128T000658Z` into a JavaScript Date Object. How can I do this without having to parse the string myself?

Comment: I personally recommend to use https://momentjs.com/ as date are generally a mess to manage, and moment do everything greatly

Comment: P.s. `console.log( new Date( "20191128T000658Z".replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, "$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6") ) );` — It doesn't seem a big problem)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME—that would be "parsing the string myself". ;-)

Comment: Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)